# Select option after right click with Selenium on PowerBi site

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, powerbi

I've this Python code to web scrape a PowerBI site:

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiZGYxNjYzNmUtOTlmZS00ODAxLWE1YTEtMjA0NjZhMzlmN2JmIiwidCI6IjljOWEzMGRlLWQ4ZDctNGFhNC05NjAwLTRiZTc2MjVmZjZjNSIsImMiOjh9")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='navigation-wrapper navigation-wrapper-big']//i[@title='Next Page']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='navigation-wrapper navigation-wrapper-big']//i[@title='Next Page']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='navigation-wrapper navigation-wrapper-big']//i[@title='Next Page']"))).click()

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/ui-view/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/exploration-container/exploration-container-modern/div/div/exploration-host/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas-modern/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container-modern[9]/transform")).perform()
action.context_click().perform()
action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[7]/drop-down-list/ng-transclude/ng-repeat[1]")).perform()
action.click().perform()
driver.quit()
```

The code above gets me to this point:

[image]

The last two line of the code are supposed to click `Show as a table` but that doesn't happen. How do I click this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on `Show as a table` use the following `xpath`.I have tested couple of times and it is working fine.

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@title='Show as a table']")))
```

**Code**:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiZGYxNjYzNmUtOTlmZS00ODAxLWE1YTEtMjA0NjZhMzlmN2JmIiwidCI6IjljOWEzMGRlLWQ4ZDctNGFhNC05NjAwLTRiZTc2MjVmZjZjNSIsImMiOjh9")
for i in range(4):
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='navigation-wrapper navigation-wrapper-big']//i[@title='Next Page']"))).click()

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/ui-view/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/exploration-container/exploration-container-modern/div/div/exploration-host/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas-modern/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container-modern[9]/transform")).perform()
action.context_click().perform()
element=WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@title='Show as a table']")))
action.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

Comment: That works. The only thing I've noticed is that `action.move_to_element(element).click().perform()` also opens the right click menu. I think this is because of the `action.context_click().perform()`. Do you know if there's a way to prevent the right click menu when the last line is executed?

Comment: Ok.I'll check and let you know if I have got an answer? Meanwhile can you try this to check if it works `action.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()`